# Making intellisene work on custom file types in VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, razor, intellisense, file-extension

I have an MVC5 project with javascript files in it.
I need to include in some of those js files C# razor like code (shared const, etc as my c# code).

to do this, I made a new file type (.csjs) and a custom view engine to render these files as razor views.

so far so good, but I don't have intellisense as these .csjs files are not recognized.
what is the simplest/best way to add razor intellisense to my new file type ?

thanks !